# Hibernate JPA generic IdField not detected after updating hibernate version

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm migrating my app from an old version of hibernate to a more recent one (6.0.2.Final)

In my code, I have a parent entity class that group all columns that are generic between tables and define a generic getter to get an IdClass instance for each tables :

Parent class :

```java
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "USER_CREATION", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private String auditUtilisateurCreation;

    ...

    //Refer to the IdClass object of the classes 
    public abstract Object getId();

    ...
}
```

Entity class :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARAM_CODES")
@IdClass(ParamCodesId.class)
@Data
public class ParamCodes extends Entity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FIELD")
    private String field;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "ORDER")
    private Long order;
    
    ...

   
    @Override
    public ParamCodeLibelleId getId() {
        return new ParamCodesId(field, code);
    }
}
```

Id class :

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"field", "code" })
@ToString(of = { "field", "code" })
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ParamCodesId implements Serializable {
    private String field;
    private String code;
}
```

After the upgrade I now have a message telling me that `An entity cannot be annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass, @Inheritance will be ignored`
I've tried few things :

- Keeping only the @MappedSuperclass on Entity => The Id column is not found in my query
- Keeping only the @Inheritance on Entity => The columns from Entity (like USER_CREATION) are not found while updating the database
- Adding a column named id as @Transient in the child class => Not queryable by my request
- Adding a column named id as @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false) in the child class => Unknown column id in field list

I'm unable to find a way to have both the generic fields like USER_CREATION and the id still be detected by requests like :

```java
@Repository
public class JpaParamCodeLibelleRepository {

    ...

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public List<ParamCodes> getExisingEntity(List<ParamCodesId> ids) {
        Query querySelect = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT e FROM ParamCodes e WHERE e.id in (:ids)", ParamCodes.class);
        return querySelect.setParameter("ids", ids).getResultList();
    }
}
```

What's the right way to do this ?

Comment: You have what look like very very different entities using the same table, but with different IDs? There is no version that will work, as nothing uniquely identifies a row across all the different entity types- how do you define such a table? That root Entity really should have a simple Id that defines the ID for all rows regardless of type. If not, then what you have are completely disparate entities - use MappedSuperclass and define the table on each subclass. Treat your ParamCodes as a proper entity and it should work - your query is missing an "id" embeddable property for the ParamCodesId

Comment: Is this the real code? The query `SELECT e FROM ParamCodes e WHERE e.id in (:ids)` doesn't look right at all as the class `ParamCodes` you shared doesn't have an `id` field. I have the impression you have  a bunch of small mapping errors that have snowballed into something that is tricky to grok. Also you must remove `@Data` from your entities. It adds an equals and hashcode that will produce weird behaviour. If you are new to hibernate, please spend time reading a book and the manual as it's a complex technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is to remove the @Inheritance from the `Entity` class.
Without it the HQL is not able to interpret the query bellow because the `e.id` is not mapped anymore to the getId from the `Entity` :

```
SELECT e FROM ParamCodes e WHERE e.id in (:ids)
```

Instead I just remove the `.id` since `e` by itself is already used as a `ParamCodesId` by hibernate so the query now look like :

```
SELECT e FROM ParamCodes e WHERE e in (:ids)
```

And the `Entity` class now only have the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation and the abstract `getId` method is removed since it's not used anymore  :

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "USER_CREATION", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private String auditUtilisateurCreation;

    ...
}
```